# What can you do in FQL that you cannot with the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to figure out what are the cases where FQL has features which the Graph API doesn't.

I tried to find the answer in the docs, but as many others have pointed out, they aren't the clearest or the most complete. To make things more difficult, a lot of the blogs commenting on the Developer platform are now dated too.

So, what can FQL do that the Graph API can't?

Comment: What is the purpose of the question? Based on what your app will do you'll find out which part of each technology is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FQL has a WHERE clause, which graph API doesn't have any equivalent of. I'm talking of something more sophisticated than just getting object connections (like user's friends). Examples: get user's friends who are also app users and online in chat, get all events which start tomorrow and not created by myself, etc, etc.

Besides that FQL is more like an extension to the graph API rather than something independent and is used to make queries on graph objects.